# USB Device not recoganized: Connecting Android Phone to laptop via USB C

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-2

I have a problem connecting Huawei P20 Lite to laptop via USB C. It used to work but recently it doesn't work any more.

[image]

[image]
I tried installing Hisuite V9.0.3.300 below

https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/hisuite/

I also trid installing usb driver
https://zfirmware.com/huawei-p20-lite-usb-driver/

Windows 7
Huawei p20 lite

Comment: Try to connect the telephone to other machine to check if it works fine. Change Mobile phone Cable and uninstall the USB driver. Download the motherland and USB from PC Manufacturer to check.

Comment: it seems my usb c end of the able has an issue.